# std::inserter with set - insert to begin() or end()?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, iterator, set

I have some code that looks like this:

```
std::set<int> s1, s2, out;

// ... s1 and s2 are populated ...

std::set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                      s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                      std::inserter(out, out.end()));
```

I've read inserts can be done in amortized constant time if the value being inserted to the set immediately follows the iterator given as a "hint".  This would obviously be beneficial when running the set intersection, especially since everything being written to `out` is already in sorted order.

How do I guarantee this optimal performance?  When creating the `std::inserter`, `out` is empty so `out.begin() == out.end()` so I can't see it makes any difference whether I specify `out.begin()` or `out.end()` as the hint.  However, if this is interpreted at inserting every element at `begin()`, it doesn't seem that I would get the optimum algorithmic performance.  Can this be done better?

Comment: @Ahsleys: At least by picking `end` you don't pessimize the algorithm since there is no following element (thus economizing one comparison). I do wonder however (as you are) if the iterator you pass will actually evolve or stuck at the beginning / end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom functor instead of `std::inserter` and re-call `out.end()` every time a new element is inserted.

Alternatively, if your values are sorted descendingly, `out.begin()` will be fine.

Comment: So, essentially, write my own `end_inserter` which always calls `end()` when inserting?  I'll give that a go...

Comment: for a set, iterators are never invalidated, except for an element that was removed, so you don't need to re-call `out.end()` each time, your other solution is correct though, to get the one before the end. Note that for C++11, it has changed constant if it belongs just _before_ the hint.

Answer (score 5):

I've chosen Alexander Gessler's answer as the 'correct' answer, because it led me to this solution, which I thought I would post anyway.  I've written a `last_inserter()`, which guarantees that the insert position is always an iterator to the last element (or begin() if empty), because `set` wants an iterator to the element *preceding* the actual insert position for best performance (so not end() - that would be one after the actual insert position).

The usage as per the original example is like this:

```
std::set<int> s1, s2, out;

// ... s1 and s2 are populated ...

std::set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                      s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                      last_inserter(out));  // note no iterator provided
```

This guarantees that the insert hint is always an iterator to the last element, hopefully providing best-case performance when using an output iterator to a set with a sorted range, as above.

Below is my implementation.  I think it's platform specific to Visual C++ 2010's STL implementation, because it's based heavily on the existing `insert_iterator`, and I can only get it working by deriving from `std::_Outit`.  If anyone knows how to make this portable, let me know:

```
// VC10 STL wants this to be a checked output iterator.  I haven't written one, but
// this needs to be defined to silence warnings about this.
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

template<class Container>
class last_inserter_iterator : public std::_Outit {
public:
    typedef last_inserter_iterator<Container> _Myt;
    typedef Container container_type;
    typedef typename Container::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename Container::value_type _Valty;

    last_inserter_iterator(Container& cont)
        : container(cont)
    {
    }

    _Myt& operator=(const _Valty& _Val)
    {
        container.insert(get_insert_hint(), _Val);
        return (*this);
    }

    _Myt& operator=(_Valty&& _Val)
    {
        container.insert(get_insert_hint(), std::forward<_Valty>(_Val));
        return (*this);
    }

    _Myt& operator*()
    {
        return (*this);
    }

    _Myt& operator++()
    {
        return (*this);
    }

    _Myt& operator++(int)
    {
        return (*this);
    }

protected:
    Container& container;

    typename Container::iterator get_insert_hint() const
    {
        // Container is empty: no last element to insert ahead of; just insert at begin.
        if (container.empty())
            return container.begin();
        else
        {
            // Otherwise return iterator to last element in the container.  std::set wants the
            // element *preceding* the insert position as a hint, so this should be an iterator
            // to the last actual element, not end().
            return (--container.end());
        }
    }
};

template<typename Container>
inline last_inserter_iterator<Container> last_inserter(Container& cont)
{
    return last_inserter_iterator<Container>(cont);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01553_source.html

```
insert_iterator&
operator=(typename _Container::value_type&& __value)
{
  iter = container->insert(iter, std::move(__value));
  ++iter;
  return *this;
}
```

Where `iter` originally pointed to the iterator you passed to `std::inserter`. So iter will always point to one past the value you just inserted and if you're inserting in order, should be optimally efficient.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) also notes that loops inserting elements in order (as set intersection does) should use `end` as the hint, as the insertion will then happen just *before* the hint (which is then constant since C++11, while previously it had to be *after* the hint)